# How to add multiple fields

Tags: entities

Let's say, I have a `text field` which I use it as a phone number field. I set the number of values to `unlimited`, so people can enter more than one number.

However, I want to use another `text field` for the definition of that number. Such as:

```
Name    Number
====    ======
Home    123456
OFfice  234567
Mobile  456789
```

How can I combine these two fields and require the Name field to be filled when each time a number field is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is [field_collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection):

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.

You can make a [compound field in code as this Phase2 Blog Post describes](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/) .... maybe there's a module for a compound field, but its usually not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this using the [Double Field](https://drupal.org/project/double_field) module:

> Double field is a small module written to provide extensions to
>   Drupal's core Fields. By this module you can divide your fields into
>   two seporate parts.
>
> For the moment it includes the following sub-widget types:
>
> - Textfield
> - Select list
> - Single checkbox
> - Textarea